# Remove specific string after specific words in python

Tags: python, string

I have couple of lines in a utf encoded text file as shown below

```
Analog Objects.D-13FT0813.MPM.FormationWater.AccVolumeTotal.ProcessValue    5   "mÂ³"   "Item value"    "
Status Objects.D-13FT1313.MPM.ActiveTemperatureTransmitter.ProcessValue 3   ""  "Item value"    "
```

What I want is to remove all the text after "ProcessValue" from both the lines and then saved the file again. I have used the following code but didn't get the desired result. Appreciate if some one could help me. My code is

```
import codecs
with open(r"test.txt", 'r+') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    fp.seek(0)
    fp.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        split_string = line.split(".ProcessValue")
        line = split_string[0]
        print(line)
        fp.write(line)
```

Comment: Add example output

Comment: In output everything is erased. In test.txt file I have couple of lines like
Analog Objects.D-13FT0813.MPM.FormationWater.AccVolumeTotal.ProcessValue 5 "mÂ³" "Item value" "

Status Objects.D-13FT1313.MPM.ActiveTemperatureTransmitter.ProcessValue 3 "" "Item value" "

Comment: The indentation needs fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy fix for your problem, I dont know if theres a lot more going on and you absolutely dont want to close the file in between operations, but if that's not the case, opening the file with `"w"` parameter overwrites the lines

```
txt = ""
with open(r"test.txt", 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        line = line.split(".ProcessValue")[0]
        print(line) # unnecessary
        txt += line + "\n"
with open(r"test.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(txt)
```

EDIT : Solution to leave `".ProcessValue"`

```
txt = ""
with open(r"test.txt", 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        splitStr = ".ProcessValue"
        index = line.find(splitStr)
        if index > 0:
            txt += line[:index + len(splitStr)] + "\n"
with open(r"test.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(txt)
```

Comment: Hi,
Thankyou for your response
After running the code it is also removing .ProcessValue
I want to remove whole text after .ProcessValue
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I thought that was your goal since you used `line.split('.ProcessValue')`. This is the reason why other user are asking you to edit your post with a desired output. We cannot guess what output you need.

Comment: Any thoughts how to do this ? While I am editing my post

Comment: @usmankhan edited my answer with a solution.

Comment: It worked!
Thank you all for this help specially Titouan L